# Facebook redirect after registration

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Fb registration in my site.I want to redirect it to my custom page (under the same domain) after registration.. how should I code? anyone please help me....

I am using the registration link in the FB login popup. Code is here...

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Registration is done. But after registration it is redirected to the facebook profile.I want it to be redirected to my domain.

Exactly in the site : https://www.wimdu.com/users/login#signin

Comment: Whats your code for the fb registration??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=<APPLICATION_ID>&
         redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URL>&
         fields=name,gender,first_name,last_name,location,email"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="500"
    height="400">
</iframe>
```

Facebook will call the redirect url with a POST request containing the information within a signed request. It will always do a top redirect.